VSCode PHPDebug ignores breakpoints on a project inside Docker
I have a Laravel project running inside Docker container on WSL2. Xdebug.log shows successful connection: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003. When I set a breakpoint and try to run the debugger though, nothing is being catched, and debugger never stops.
launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "php-laravel debugger",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003,
        "pathMappings": {
          "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}/server"
        },
      },
    ]
  }

docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini:
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_upon_error=yes
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log

Relevant parts of docker-compose.yml:
  server:
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./server:/var/www/html  
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"  
      - "9003:9003"
    environment:
      XDEBUG_MODE: debug
      XDEBUG_CLIENT_HOST: host.docker.internal 
      XDEBUG_CLIENT_PORT: 9003    
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"  

Edit: 
As soon as I remove the ports: - "9003:9003" line, XDebug is not able to connect anymore.
[1] [Config] INFO: Control socket set up succesfully: '@xdebug-ctrl.1'
[1] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[1] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'host.docker.internal:9003', poll success, but error: Operation in progress (29).
[1] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

Edit 2: 
wsl hostname -I in xdebug.client_host seemed to do the trick, connection is established. As soon as I rebuild the container and turn on debugger, it throws an error: Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException: The "--host" option does not exist. , seemingly relating to CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000 line in the Dockerfile.
When I remove this line, error disappears, but I cannot interact with breakpoints whatsoever. It is as if VSCode is resolving exceptions in the background somehow, because all I can see is the logs that look like this: [24] [Step Debug] DEBUG: Breakpoint 240002 (type: line). [24] [Step Debug] DEBUG: D: Breakpoint 240002 (type: line) is already resolved.

ports:       - "8000:8000"        - "9003:9003" You do not need the - "9003:9003" part here. It's Xdebug that connects to the debug client (VSCode in your case) and NOT other way around. Therefore you do not need to forward 9003 into the container. Right it looks like VSCode cannot listen on Xdebug port because it's already used by Docker. I would definitely start here. If it's still the same -- show the full Xdebug lo -- what it has after that initial "connected" line. It may give some hints.

Thank you for the reply. I added some clarifications regarding ports.

Not sure now. But looks like it's networking. You said "inside Docker container on WSL2" -- might be the reason. Please check this doc from Xdebug author -- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W-NzNtExf5C4eOu3rRQm1WlWnbW44u3ANDDA49d3FD4/ -- try xdebug://gateway instead P.S. What Xdebug was showing when you had that ports: - "9003:9003" line present?

The doc proved to be really helpful and I am able to connect. Now there are other issues, I added them as well to the post for convenience. Seems to be somewhat of a conundrum. Would you recommend going local at this point?

php artisan serve is what launches your web server (Laravel own one) and the --host is a valid parameter, at least in v10 (I do not have any with v11 to check). Cannot help with resolving breakpoints -- I'm not using VSCode (PhpStorm user here) so do not know what exactly it does at that stage. Although that entry looks like a Xdebug log (seems like you are using Xdebug login at the maximum level of (10?), default 7 should be enough).

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, it indeed was not the php artisan serve. I refreshed the endpoint one more time and now the breakpoints work as expected.
